# Simulate a class of type enum

Tags: java, class, enums, simulate

how can I do to simulate a class of type enum in java <5.0 ..??

```
public final class Week {

    private static final Day[] _week = {Day.MONDAY, Day.TUESDAY, Day.WEDNESDAY, Day.THURSDAY, Day.FRIDAY, Day.SATURDAY, Day.SUNDAY};

    public static Day getDayOfWeek(final int index) {
        if (index >= 1 && index <= 7) {
            return _week[index - 1];
        }
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Invalid index [1..7]");
    }

    public static final class Day {
        public static final Day MONDAY = new Day(1, "Monday");
        public static final Day TUESDAY = new Day(2, "Tuesday");
        public static final Day WEDNESDAY = new Day(3, "Wednesday");
        public static final Day THURSDAY = new Day(4, "Thursday");
        public static final Day FRIDAY = new Day(5, "Friday");
        public static final Day SATURDAY = new Day(6, "Saturday");
        public static final Day SUNDAY = new Day(7, "Sunday");

        private int _value;
        private String _name;

        private Day(final int value, final String name) {
            _value = value;
            _name = name;
        }

        /* (non-Javadoc)
         * @see java.lang.Object#toString()
         */
        public String toString() {
            return "[Day] " + _name;
        }

        /* (non-Javadoc)
         * @see java.lang.String#equals(java.lang.Object)
         */
        public boolean equals(Object anObject) {
            Day d = (Day)anObject;
            return _value == d._value;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] agrs) {
         System.out.println(Week.getDayOfWeek(2));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Use the typesafe enum described in effective java.  Here is an example given from [Joshua Blochs article on this](http://java.sun.com/developer/Books/shiftintojava/page1.html#replaceenums):

```
// The typesafe enum pattern
public class Suit {
    private final String name;

    private Suit(String name) { this.name = name; }

    public String toString()  { return name; }

    public static final Suit CLUBS =
        new Suit("clubs");
    public static final Suit DIAMONDS =
        new Suit("diamonds");
    public static final Suit HEARTS =
        new Suit("hearts");
    public static final Suit SPADES =
        new Suit("spades");
}
```

If you want your typesafe enum to be [Serializable](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html), remember to control reconstruction via the `readResolve` method.

Comment: add equals and hashCode support :)

Comment: thx, so how it works. If i do thos Suit("spades") What will I get ..??

Comment: @helios, when controlling construction like this the equals method is equivalent to using `==` as there will only ever be one instance of each distinct Suit.

Comment: @Mercer you use this by calling `Suit.CLUBS` or `Suit.SPADES` just like you would if Suit was a Java 5 enum.  If you want to resolve a `Suit` from a string then you need to provide another method that will compare the string to each of the Suit names to see which one matches.

Answer (score 4):

Joshua Bloch wrote, long ago, [an article](http://java.sun.com/developer/Books/shiftintojava/page1.html#replaceenums) explaining it.

Answer (score 0):

Joshua Bloch shows you how in the first edition of his "Effective Java".  I have to go to work, so I can't type in details now.  More to follow.

Comment: Seven years after the fact and now this is down voted?  Moderators, take note.

Answer (score 0):

The solution Krock and Riduidel are suggesting is pretty neat, but AFAIK a `switch-case` statement won't be possible as it's applicable only for convertible `int` values and `enum` constants.
`switch-case` combination is a nice feature, more readable than a bunch of `if`s (BTW: `switch-case` will be compiled as a bunch of `if`s anyway, correct?). So, to complete the discussed pattern, could someone tell whether there is a quick way to enable this patteren with functionality allowing `switch-case`? Adding an `int` property and getter for it seems the simplest way, but is it the optimal?